# How to append parameters to string in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this method and I need to concatenating parameters so the result should be. Any idea how to do it?

```
getTyreLabels?width=m125.00&aspect=25&rim=13.00&season=SU&time=269742091

- (NSURL *)getTyreLabels:(NSString*)width :(NSInteger*)aspect : (NSInteger*)rim : (NSString*)season : (NSString*)pattern : (NSInteger*)time;
{
    return [[self getBaseUrl] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"getTyreLabels"];
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment when downvoting

Comment: Also, your method naming isn't good at all. (I also didn't down vote).

Comment: use `return [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@%@%@", oldData, newData1, newData2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the string you put at the beginning is the desired output.

In which case your method should be something like...

```
- (NSString *)parameterStringWithWidth:(NSString *)width
                                aspect:(NSInteger)aspect
                                   rim:(NSInteger)rim
                                season:(NSString *)season
                               pattern:(NSString *)pattern
                                  time:(NSInteger)time
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getTyreLabels?width=m%@&aspect=%ld&rim=%ld&season=%@&time=%ld", width, (long)aspect, (long)rim, season, (long)time];
}
```

That will return the string. Not the URL but you should be able to get the point from this.

Note the way the method name is constructed. It makes it MUCH easier to call it from somewhere else as you can see what each parameter is relating to.

```
NSString *theString = [self parameterStringWithWidth:@"125.00" aspect:25 rim:13 season:@"SU" pattern:@"" time:269742091];
```

This will result in `theString` being the value you put in your question.

Comment: Thanks, just a quick question, what is the differene between %@ and %ld?

Comment: @GibboK Formatting strings depends on the values that you are putting in. Take a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html note that `NSInteger` has to be casted up into a `long int` to be formatted safely into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you want something like this -

```
- (NSURL *)getTyreLabelsWithWidth:(NSString*)width
                        andAspect:(NSInteger)aspect
                           andRim:(NSInteger)rim
                        andSeason:(NSString *)season 
                       andPattern:(NSString*)pattern
                          andTime:(NSInteger)time
{
    NSString *stringToAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat@"getTyreLabels?width=%@&aspect=%d&rim=%d&season=%d&time=%d", width, aspect, rim, season, time]; 

 return [[self getBaseUrl] URLByAppendingPathComponent: stringToAppend];
}
```